# PDF preview like Mail App

Tags: iphone, pdf

I am looking for a PDF preview feature similar to the one available when a PDF is received via mail in iPad mail app. It has options like Print/Mail and an Open In menu. Do you have any idea is it an apple's custom implementation or part of framework. I couldn't find in QLPreviewController and UIDocInteract framework.

Answer (score 0):

its very simple to implement .. you will just load `NSURLRequest` with the `NSURL` that hold the pdf path into `UIWebView`.

for example :

```
NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iPadHIG" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];

[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfUrl]];

webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Comment: No. This is not what I am looking for. If you take a look at ipad mail app. The way the attachment opens up and options we have like Mail/Print and Open In. All this we cant have in a webview.

Comment: The way they preview the PDF its self is to load it in a webView .. I'm very sure of that .. for the features i think you are talking about the popOver that presented from the toolbar which contain the title of the pdf and done button and the action button , right ?

Comment: Correct. I am looking for those features inbuilt with any of the iOS frameworks. It seems there is none so I am creating a custom one.